# SignalR on Webpack and TypeScript: cannot find module './NodeHttpClient'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, signalr, signalr.client

I'm trying to set a SignalR client in an Angular app. There is Webpack which does the job. And TypeScript, of course.

Package.json is

```
{
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies" " { ... }
  "dependencies": {
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

The TypeScript code is:

```
import { HubConnectionBuilder } from '@aspnet/signalr';

@Component({
    selector: 'stream-details',
    templateUrl: './stream-details.component.html'
})
export class StreamDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() summary: any;

constructor(private deviceService: StreamService) {
}

ngOnInit() {

    let connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('/streamingHub')
        .build()

    connection
        .start()
        .then(() => connection.stream('SubscribeToStream', 'stream123'));
}
}
```

When the app is running, the error is:

> NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module './NodeHttpClient'

Why is not this NodeHttpClient.js file included? What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package @aspnet/signalr 1.1.0 doesn't show this issue anymore. I cannot reproduce it on a new angular app.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with 1.1.0, same error, last working version is npm install @aspnet/signalr@1.0.4

Comment: @pingo then your only chance is to fill an issue on the official repo and provide a sample app where the error is reproduced.

Answer (score 4):

This prolem persists right now. There is also an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/3254) on github. The issue is closed however according to my observations the problem still the case.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading your @aspnet/signalr version to 1.0.0 solving the issue.

Comment: Yeap, this is working. This is a solution, it got me unblocked. But on the long run is not users would want.